# Scale ImageView aswell as Image

Tags: android, imageview, scale, pinchzoom

Currently, I have an XML file with lots of imageviews in it that can be scrolled through using navigation buttons. These imageviews can be rotated, scrolled and moved but when they are they will leave the bounds of the imageview and so you cant see parts or all of them.

Is there any way that I can resize the imageview programmatically at the same rate as the image is being scaled?

Alternatively, is there a way that i can draw the images to a canvas and each of them can be scaled individually?

Comment: Can you just use `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`?

Comment: "These imageviews can be rotated, scrolled and moved but when they are they will leave the bounds of the imageview".  This doesn't make sense.  Please try to rephrase.  An ImageView can't go outside it's own bounds by definition.

Comment: Sorry, What i meant to say is that the image's inside the imageviews are scaled and go outside the bounds of their views.

Also, I currently do have them set to wrap_content but when the image inside the imageview changes the imageview doesnt.